# Rate of increase of $y = \sqrt{2x + 2}$ when $x$ is...

Tags: calculus

A point with coordinates $(x,y)$ moves along the curve in such a way that the rate of increase of $x$ has the constant value of $0.01$ units per second. Find the rate of increase of $y = \sqrt{2x + 2}$ at the instant when $x = 1$.

I am given the gradient at a point on the curve.

Also, I am given the equation of the curve.

I don't wish to know the exact answer as I would like to work it out myself, but I really need help in understanding this question and what equation I am supposed to use to get the answer.

Comment: Do you know the function $f$ such that $y=f(x(t))$?

Comment: they give me y=squarootof(2x+2)

Comment: Suppose you wanted either the rate of increase in terms of x units or if x had the constant rate of 1.  Would you know what to do then?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=0.01 \quad \rightarrow \quad x(t)=0.01t +c
$$
and, if $x(0)=0$, we have $c=0$. Now:
$$
x(t)=1\quad \rightarrow \quad 0.01t=1 \quad \rightarrow \quad t=100
$$
From 
$$
y=\sqrt{2x(t)+2}=\sqrt{0.02 t+2}
$$
find $\frac{dy}{dt}$ and evaluate it at $t=100$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - but i'm having trouble understanding it?